# Can't open file dialog internet explorer 11 windows 7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

file dialog doesn't opened in internet explorer 11 on windows 7. On windows 10 all works correctly. Why?

```
<div onclick="selectFile()">Open</div>

    function selectFile() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'file';
  input.onchange = function () {
    console.log(input.files[0]);
  };
 input.click();
}
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjJvzq

Comment: Is there any error in IE's console?

Comment: No errors, console is clear.

Comment: Have you tried if it works when you, instead of creating the file-input on the spot, just keep it hidden until you need it (either `display:hidden` or `visibility:hidden`)?

Comment: It's also possible that IE11 has a different security build-in, that prevents the file-dialog from being opened [programmatically](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/programmatically), and only allows it to be opened as a direct result from user-interaction.

Comment: @myfunkyside. yes it works correctly, but i can't understand why it not works when i create input programmatically.

Comment: Probably due to similar security restrictions. Many malicious sites use those kinds of techniques to trick people into giving up personal information, so the browser just makes it impossible to do so. Now, why IE11 has stricter rules than all the others, I don't know, IE has always been a bit of an outlier when it comes to implementation of well pretty much everything on the web. Programmers all around the world hate them for it :)